# Entering keys doesn't work on 18.04 with gnome-tweaks

Tags: keyboard-layout, gnome-tweak-tool, special-characters, compose-key

I have a Hungarian keyboard, here's the layout.

[image]

I've just updated to 18.04 (from 16.04) and now I can't enter `[AltGr]+[<key>]` and `[letter]` or `[AltGr]+[Shift]+[<key>]` and `[letter]` combinations anymore. What I get is just separate glyphs/character, e.g. instead of an **à** (*a* with grave accent), which used to work by entering `[AltGr]+[Shift]+[7]` and then hitting `a`, I now get just **´a** (**acute accent** and **a**)

I have `gnome-tweaks` installed, and I didn't know it's going to override (or rather mess up) entering key combinations. It doesn't matter if I enable Compose Key in it, or whatever key I set as Compose Key, entering keys doesn't work. Even the default example ('compose key followed by **C** and **o** will enter **©**') provided doesn't work.

Characters, that can be entered in 1 step do work, e.g. `[AltGr]+[Shift]+o` to get **Ø** works (see keyboard layout).

But characters where I first need to release keys and then hit another key don't, e.g. as described above with **à**.

[image]

I don't care how fancy this Compose Key is, I just want the old way of entering keys (based on my keyboard layout) back, because I rely on it heavily. Do I need to get rid of `gnome-tweaks`?

Comment: Take a look at [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1573755). Some of the workarounds there might help.

Comment: The first thing I would try is to create an additional user account, log in to that account, and find out if it works as expected there.

Comment: Hello Gunnar, thank you very much for the reference to the launchpad page.
It turned out, my system had no entry in 'Keyboard input method system'. I was not expecting having to select one manually after system installation. I picked iBus and it solved my character entry problem.

Comment: What surprises me is that this used to work in Ubuntu 16.04 without further work in  the Language support menu, and even during installation of 18.04 it worked when I selected the keyboard layout and types a few keys into the test textbox.

Comment: When you say "no entry", do you remember exactly what it said? I'd guess either "XIM" or "none" (probably "XIM").

Comment: The dropdown menu looked like a blank box before opening, with 0 character length, only the margins, cheesy. I should have made a screenshot of it, but I won't reinstall Ubuntu for a 3rd time. Once I opened it, there were 3 options, I went with what I could recognized, IBus.

Comment: Ok. Not sure how that could happen, but good that setting IBus was sufficient to fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, but only to document the solution that worked.

It turned out, `gnome-tweaks` was not at fault here. The culprit was the lack of a *Keyboard input method system* in *Language Support*.

[image]

After picking one from the dropdown list the character entry method (as described in the question) works. For reference, *Compose Key* is disabled in my `gnome-tweaks` installation.